# Cobol to SAS migration

Tags: cobol

I am looking for a tool which will convert Cobol code (Procedure division) logic into SAS. Cobol code is used for Banking (CC division) and it is almost 140K lines of code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not likely to find one off the shelf.

If you are to get one, it will be easist if it is built on top of technology designed for the task.

Our [DMS Software Reenginering Toolkit](https://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations) is such technology; it is used to implement custom translators between languages.   DMS has a full [IBM Enterprise COBOL front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/COBOLFrontEnd.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations), and also handles other dialects of COBOL.     It can be configured to handle a migration to arbitrary target languages; [for COBOL we presently target Java and C#](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Services/COBOLMigration.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations). SAS would be a custom target.

Given that you can transliterate code by hand at about 30 lines per day maximum, moving 140K SLOC would take 4600 man-days or 23 man-years of effort.  A team of 5 engineers would take 4 elapsed years to complete.   An automated migration is likely to take 9-18 months.