# Free tools to convert COBOL source code to VB6/VB.Net/C#/Java?

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, cobol

I have requirement to convert one of my COBOL project source code to any of the following languages VB6/VB.Net/C#. So I searched for a free(open source) tool to convert the source code from COBOL to VB6/VB.Net/C# so that instead of rewriting the entire source code I can reduce manual effort using tool. But didn't find any such tools.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A conversion of complete programs is commonly not useful, given that COBOL commonly uses precompilers, both third-party (often for `EXEC SQL` and similar) and in-house ones (often for macro extensions) and/or accesses files in a way that can't be easily migrated, especially when using ISAM or record-sequential files (especially if you use variable-length records).

If you want to access files that were used in COBOL from .NET you commonly have to change this access in COBOL first (see note at the end).

This aside - there's a company that claims to have you covered if you throw $$$ at them - see [Cobol to SAS migration](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/66462/cobol-to-sas-migration).

If you look for a free tool and only want to inspect the code and/or start with an automated  / partial conversion you may want to have a look into [Structorizer](https://github.com/fesch/Structorizer.Desktop), a tool for Nassi-Schneiderman Diagrams (NSD) that allows you to [import COBOL](https://help.structorizer.fisch.lu/index.php?menu=136) into NSDs and [export them to various languages](https://help.structorizer.fisch.lu/index.php?menu=68).
I've used that before for getting the rough layouts correct and extract specific parts; when adjusting the NSD after the import manually the export result was often useful.

Another option would be to use a free COBOL compiler available for nearly every system: [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/) to compiler your COBOL into native code (in your case likely 64bit dlls), then [calling native functions from.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code) for invoking COBOL programs.
This way "tested and working performant COBOL" stays "tested and working and performant", while being usable from .NET.
If your COBOL code has "COBOL files" you could also opt to use GnuCOBOL's EXTFH interface to access these files "directly" from .NET (using a native wrapper to the EXTFH entry point in libcob.dll) or use GnuCOBOL 4+ to write/read the files you want to share into a DB via ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the RES COBOL translator tool:
[RES - An Open Cobol To Java Translator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencobol2java/)

It seems to handle basic COBOL statements.   I'm unsure of how much of real COBOL dialects it actually handles.

It has some limitations on the quality of its translated code.  You can read my (long) assessment of it here: [Which are the best available open source tools for converting COBOL code to Java?](https://qr.ae/pvwPt7)